# how to change array output

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array "DArr" that I want to display all the content.
I use this code to set the input to the html id

```
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = [DArr];
```

the output as expected is in this format

> 1,2,3,4,5

what I want is have the output in this format

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

how can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with using `join` function :

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = DArr.join("<br />");
```

Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/join)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var dArr = [1,2,3,4,5];

dArr.forEach(
  function(val) {
    var newEl = document.createElement('div');
    newEl.textContent = val;
    output.appendChild(newEl);
  }
);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Or try this:

```js
dArr = [2,3,4,5,6];

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = dArr.join('<br/>');
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` can accept a string of HTML. You can combine this with `Array.join` to combine your output with `<br />` tags to create the desired effect:

```
var html = DArr.join('<br />');
// 1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is a property, not a function.